# Randomly set an element's top property based on parent height on render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've created a CSS twinkling star component that creates 300 `div` pixels, and places them randomly based on the viewport height and width. This works almost perfectly until mobile formatting comes into play, at which point the initial container that the stars are meant to fill has a height larger than the viewport, so the stars stop abruptly once you begin scrolling down.

Is there a way to get the height value of the component that the stars are being rendered in? My code looks like this:

```
//Stars.js
const Star = styled.div`
    animation: ${flicker} infinite;
    animation-duration: ${props => props.animationDuration + 1}s;
    animation-delay: ${props => props.animationDelay}s;
    width: ${props => props.size}px;
    height: ${props => props.size}px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: white;
`
const StarContainer = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
`
const vpHeight = window.innerHeight;
const vpWidth = window.innerWidth;
const starCount = () => {
    const count = []
    for(let i = 1; i <= 300; i++){
        count.push(i)
    }
    return count
}

const Stars = () => {

    const starsRef = useRef(null)

    return (
        <StarContainer ref={starsRef} id='star-container'>
            {starCount().map((star, i) => (
                <Star 
                key={i}
                animationDuration={Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)}
                animationDelay={Math.random() * 6}
                size={Math.random() * 5}
                style={{
                    top: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * vpHeight)}px`,
                    left: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * vpWidth)}px`,
                }} />
            ))}
        </StarContainer>
    );
}

export default Stars;
```

And the component that the stars are rendered over:

```
function Skillset() {
    const icons = images.icons
    const skillsetRef = useRef(null)
    return (
        <div ref={skillsetRef} id='skillset' className={styles.skillsetContent}>
            <Stars />
            <Header>I am a Front End Developer who specializes in React.js</Header>
            <Tag>Some of my favorite technologies include:</Tag>
            <div className={styles.iconGrid}>
                <AnimatedCards number={icons.length} data={icons} hoverText={true} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Skillset;
```

As you can see, I've tried using `useRef` to access the containing component and get the `skillsetRef.current.offsetHeight`, passing that as a prop to the `Stars` component, and setting that as the height multiplier rather than the viewport height. However it says that the value is null, and I imagine this is because of the order in which the reference is created vs when the stars component is created. I'm at a loss for what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

`skillsetRef.current` will only be available after the initial render. You could delay rendering the stars until you have the `skillsetRef.current` value

```
const [refAvailable, setRefAvailable] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
  if(!refAvailable) {
    setRefAvailable(true);
  }
}, [refAvailable]);



// Render stars only when you have the ref.current available
refAvailable && <Stars height={skillsetRef.current.offsetHeight}/>
```

Another idea would be to use top and left values as percentage instead of px.

```
style={{
  top: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}%`,
  left: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}%`,
}} />
```

You could also add some buffer to viewport height to cater for mobile browsers.

```
const vpHeight = window.innerHeight + 100;
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither way works. They both seem to return the view height for some reason. I'm not sure if the container div isn't fully expanded when it initially renders or what, since I have the height value set to `min-height: 100vh` and it expands when the children are rendered. I like the thought here though, especially the simple % solution.

Comment: Check my edited answer. Probably the 100vh is the culprit here. You can try with percentage height instead, otherwise you need window resize listener.

Comment: Yea I tried the % solution to no avail, the `StarContainer`'s height seems to be set based on the immediate render of the `Skillset` component, which apparently then adjusts its height to accommodate the other elements in it for mobile. I decided it was best to just add 200px to the star container height, and increase the z-index of the content below skillset to keep any stray stars from appearing lower than intended. Not the most elegant solution, but it works!